# 3D NAND Flash id using FTDI

Tags: nand-flash

I am trying to get Micron 3D NAND flash id using FTDI 2232H board but unable to detect using pyftdi library.Although i am detecting ftdi url like: Available interfaces:
ftdi://ftdi:4232:0:1/1   (Quad RS232-HS)
I'm using the following software to read the NAND Flash:
https://github.com/ohjeongwook/DumpFlash
[image]

Comment: Listings are better embedded in your question as a code block rather than a picture - more searchable. Is the error you're complaining about the not recognizing 'usr/bin/env' ? That sounds like a python environment setup problem, rather than anything to do with the specific code you're trying to run. Perhaps it's your path to your python executable, so it should be spelt '/usr/bin/env/python3' ?

Comment: please post the code and the terminal output as text ... a picture of text cannot be copied and tested ... also, some people are not able to view pictures

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.